# How to change transition in fullScreenCover in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to make a transition from leading.

```
.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isLoginSuccess) {
    HomeView()
}
```

It's using the default transition, from bottom. Unable to change the transition with `.transition(.move(edge: .leading))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alternative animation for fullscreen cover / modal - iOS 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62593549/alternative-animation-for-fullscreen-cover-modal-ios-14)

Comment: you can't. but you can create a custom fullscreen cover. See link above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fullScreenCover` is using the system animation when presenting (also because it plays under the hoods with UIKit, if I'm not mistaken), while `transition` modifier affects the appearance of a view when for example you use `if` or `switch` statements in the body of a view itself.

In your case you could wrap both login and home views in same body and use an `if` to show either the login or the home.

```swift
struct Root: View {
  @State var isLoginSuccess = false

  var body: some View {
    if isLoginSuccess {
      HomeView()
        .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
    } else {
      LoginView()
        .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
    }
  }
}
```

Then, when modifying the state, remember to wrap under `withAnimation` like:

```swift
withAnimation {
  isLoginSuccess = true
}
```